# managedQuery(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,null,null, null); returns null when running on device

Tags: android, mediastore

```
String projection[] = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
cursor =managedQuery(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,null,null, null);
```

this cursor is returning null when i am trying to run it on device. it works fine on emulator.

Can someone please point out if there is something that i am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: First of all, the constant should be MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
Secondly, I'm assuming you are debugging your device with the device in usb mass storage mode.. meaning your computer has access to the sdcard. I would recommend putting your device in charge only mode and try debugging like that.. This allows the sdcard to be read from the phone. If you don't have charge only mode try anything other than usb mass storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same for this code working

```
public class LoadImagesFromSDCardActivity extends Activity implements
OnItemClickListener {

/**
 * Grid view holding the images.
 **/

private GridView sdcardImages;
/**
 * Image adapter for the grid view.
 **/
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
/**
 * Display used for getting the width of the screen. 
 **/
private Display display;
ImageView imgView;

/**
 * Creates the content view, sets up the grid, the adapter, and the click listener.
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 **/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    // Request progress bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    setupViews();
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); 
    loadImages();
}

/**
 * Free up bitmap related resources.
 **/
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    final GridView grid = sdcardImages;
    final int count = grid.getChildCount();
    ImageView v = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        v = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i);
        ((BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable()).setCallback(null);
    }
}
/**
 * Setup the grid view.
 **/
private void setupViews() {
    sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
    sdcardImages.setNumColumns(display.getWidth()/95);
    sdcardImages.setClipToPadding(false);
    sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(LoadImagesFromSDCardActivity.this);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()); 
    sdcardImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
}
/**
 * Load images.
 */
private void loadImages() {
    final Object data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (data == null) {
        new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute();
    } else {
        final LoadedImage[] photos = (LoadedImage[]) data;
        if (photos.length == 0) {
            new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute();
        }
        for (LoadedImage photo : photos) {
            addImage(photo);
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Add image(s) to the grid view adapter.
 * 
 * @param value Array of LoadedImages references
 */
private void addImage(LoadedImage... value) {
    for (LoadedImage image : value) {
        imageAdapter.addPhoto(image);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

/**
 * Save bitmap images into a list and return that list. 
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
 */
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    final GridView grid = sdcardImages;
    final int count = grid.getChildCount();
    final LoadedImage[] list = new LoadedImage[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final ImageView v = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i);
        list[i] = new LoadedImage(((BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
    }

    return list;
}
/**
 * Async task for loading the images from the SD card. 
 * 
 * @author Mihai Fonoage
 *
 */
class LoadImagesFromSDCard extends AsyncTask<Object, LoadedImage, Object> {

    /**
     * Load images from SD Card in the background, and display each image on the screen. 
     *  
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); 
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Bitmap newBitmap = null;
        Uri uri = null;            

        // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
        // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Return all rows
                null,       
                null); 
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
        int size = cursor.getCount();
        // If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.
        if (size == 0) {
            //No Images available, post some message to the user
        }
        int imageID = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID);
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true);
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    if (newBitmap != null) {
                        publishProgress(new LoadedImage(newBitmap));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Error fetching image, try to recover
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    /**
     * Add a new LoadedImage in the images grid.
     *
     * @param value The image.
     */
    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(LoadedImage... value) {
        addImage(value);
    }
    /**
     * Set the visibility of the progress bar to false.
     * 
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }
}

/**
 * Adapter for our image files. 
 * 
 * @author Mihai Fonoage
 *
 */
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext; 
    private ArrayList<LoadedImage> photos = new ArrayList<LoadedImage>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) { 
        mContext = context; 
    } 

    public void addPhoto(LoadedImage photo) { 
        photos.add(photo); 
    } 

    public int getCount() { 
        return photos.size(); 
    } 

    public Object getItem(int position) { 
        return photos.get(position); 
    } 

    public long getItemId(int position) { 
        return position; 
    } 

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        final ImageView imageView; 
        if (convertView == null) { 
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext); 
        } else { 
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView; 
        } 
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photos.get(position).getBitmap());
        return imageView; 
    } 
}

/**
 * A LoadedImage contains the Bitmap loaded for the image.
 */
private static class LoadedImage {
    Bitmap mBitmap;

    LoadedImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mBitmap;
    }
}
/**
 * When an image is clicked, load that image as a puzzle. 
 */
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {        
    int columnIndex = 0;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); 

        FileInputStream is = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, true);
            Log.i("called","called");
            imgView.setImageBitmap(useThisBitmap);
            bitmap.recycle();
            //Display bitmap (useThisBitmap)
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            //Try to recover
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (bis != null) {
                    bis.close();
                }
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
                cursor.close();
                projection = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
  }

}
```

And

main.xml

```
  <GridView  
    android:id="@+id/sdcard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" 
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    ></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm confused, is this a solution or another question?

Comment: just a simple observation: use `imageCursor.moveToFirst()` which will return false if the cursor is empty instead of `cursor.getCount()` because is more faster. Here it is: `if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //No Images available, post some message to the user
        }`

Answer (score -1):

http://www.androidsnippets.com/list-all-music-files

Comment: Broken link. For this reason the link answer are bad.